# How to get root access on Linux embedded system?

Tags: dump

I've saved from the trash bin an embedded system using an OPOS6UL (http://www.armadeus.org/wiki/index.php?title=OPOS6UL) as Single Board Computer.
It was easy to get an UART console, but I cannot log in because I don't know the password.

What can be ways to get root access ?

I think :

- try common passwords/development kit default password => not working
- brute-force the password : too long, I have to wait several seconds between retries
- dump the eMMC to read /etc/passwd : hardware dump is impossible, is it possible from u-boot ?
- any other idea ?

Here is the boot log :

```
U-Boot SPL 2016.05 (Sep 22 2017 - 16:24:46)
Trying to boot from MMC1


U-Boot 2016.05 (Sep 22 2017 - 16:24:46 +0200)

CPU:   Freescale i.MX6UL rev1.1 at 396 MHz
Reset cause: POR
Board: OPOS6UL
DRAM:  256 MiB
MMC:   FSL_SDHC: 0
Video: 800x480x18
Net:   FEC [PRIME]
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
1152122 bytes read in 140 ms (7.8 MiB/s)
5243120 bytes read in 265 ms (18.9 MiB/s)
27370 bytes read in 116 ms (229.5 KiB/s)
Kernel image @ 0x82000000 [ 0x000000 - 0x5000f0 ]
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 88000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x88000000
   Using Device Tree in place at 88000000, end 88009ae9

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.8.10 (microlide@dev-armadeus) (gcc version 6.2.1 20161016 (Linaro GCC 6.2-2016.11) ) #1 PREEMPT Mon Oct 23 18:04:19 CEST 2017
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc075] revision 5 (ARMv7), cr=10c53c7d
[    0.000000] CPU: div instructions available: patching division code
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt:Machine model: Armadeus Systems OPOS6UL SoM on OPOS6ULDev board
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 16 MiB at 0x8f000000
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 65024
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttymxc0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 222416K/262144K available (8192K kernel code, 365K rwdata, 2296K rodata, 1024K init, 8206K bss, 23344K reserved, 16384K cma-reserved, 0K highmem)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
[    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
[    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
[    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xd0800000 - 0xff800000   ( 752 MB)
[    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xd0000000   ( 256 MB)
[    0.000000]     pkmap   : 0xbfe00000 - 0xc0000000   (   2 MB)
[    0.000000]     modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xbfe00000   (  14 MB)
[    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc0900000   (9184 kB)
[    0.000000]       .init : 0xc0c00000 - 0xc0d00000   (1024 kB)
[    0.000000]       .data : 0xc0d00000 - 0xc0d5b6c0   ( 366 kB)
[    0.000000]        .bss : 0xc0d5d000 - 0xc1560bc0   (8207 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Running RCU self tests
[    0.000000] Preemptible hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  RCU lockdep checking is enabled.
[    0.000000]  Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 32.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
[    0.000000] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 41ns
[    0.000018] sched_clock: 32 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 89478484971ns
[    0.000068] clocksource: mxc_timer1: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 79635851949 ns
[    0.002539] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.002617] Lock dependency validator: Copyright (c) 2006 Red Hat, Inc., Ingo Molnar
[    0.002645] ... MAX_LOCKDEP_SUBCLASSES:  8
[    0.002669] ... MAX_LOCK_DEPTH:          48
[    0.002692] ... MAX_LOCKDEP_KEYS:        8191
[    0.002714] ... CLASSHASH_SIZE:          4096
[    0.002734] ... MAX_LOCKDEP_ENTRIES:     32768
[    0.002756] ... MAX_LOCKDEP_CHAINS:      65536
[    0.002777] ... CHAINHASH_SIZE:          32768
[    0.002797]  memory used by lock dependency info: 5167 kB
[    0.002820]  per task-struct memory footprint: 1536 bytes
[    0.002902] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 48.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=240000)
[    0.002951] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.003414] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.003453] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.007619] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.009185] Setting up static identity map for 0x80100000 - 0x80100058
[    0.018704] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.075673] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 2 part 30 variant 7 rev 5
[    0.077702] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.079738] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.088450] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.096017] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.121662] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.235335] No ATAGs?
[    0.235421] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.235466] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.239662] imx6ul-pinctrl 20e0000.iomuxc: initialized IMX pinctrl driver
[    0.342756] mxs-dma 1804000.dma-apbh: initialized
[    0.354723] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.356743] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.357205] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.357732] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.371759] i2c i2c-0: IMX I2C adapter registered
[    0.371861] i2c i2c-0: can't use DMA, using PIO instead.
[    0.375130] i2c i2c-1: IMX I2C adapter registered
[    0.375243] i2c i2c-1: can't use DMA, using PIO instead.
[    0.375715] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    0.376298] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.376342] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.376490] PTP clock support registered
[    0.378804] Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
[    0.386157] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    0.386451] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[    0.386493] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    0.386657] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    0.386750] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    0.387093] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    0.393353] clocksource: Switched to clocksource mxc_timer1
[    0.394955] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.395154] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.469809] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.473710] TCP established hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.473882] TCP bind hash table entries: 2048 (order: 4, 73728 bytes)
[    0.475577] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 2048 bind 2048)
[    0.475951] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 2, 20480 bytes)
[    0.476446] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 2, 20480 bytes)
[    0.478586] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.481133] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.481189] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.481223] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.481255] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.490799] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 11264 bytes)
[    0.494511] workingset: timestamp_bits=30 max_order=16 bucket_order=0
[    0.560068] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.560501] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.560544] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.562075] fuse init (API version 7.25)
[    0.587295] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.587357] io scheduler deadline registered
[    0.588550] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
[    0.599626] lcd_backlight supply power not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.636295] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 100x30
[    0.653101] mxsfb 21c8000.lcdif: initialized
[    0.657898] imx-sdma 20ec000.sdma: Direct firmware load for imx/sdma/sdma-imx6q.bin failed with error -2
[    0.657979] imx-sdma 20ec000.sdma: external firmware not found, using ROM firmware
[    0.684856] 2020000.serial: ttymxc0 at MMIO 0x2020000 (irq = 18, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
[    1.346291] console [ttymxc0] enabled
[    1.354793] 2024000.serial: ttymxc7 at MMIO 0x2024000 (irq = 19, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
[    1.367774] 21e8000.serial: ttymxc1 at MMIO 0x21e8000 (irq = 219, base_baud = 5000000) is a IMX
[    1.459475] brd: module loaded
[    1.508714] loop: module loaded
[    1.523143] libphy: Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
[    1.530081] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
[    1.535280] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
[    1.543022] CAN device driver interface
[    1.554083] flexcan 2090000.flexcan: device registered (reg_base=d0988000, irq=23)
[    1.567529] flexcan 2094000.flexcan: device registered (reg_base=d0990000, irq=24)
[    1.585840] pps pps0: new PPS source ptp0
[    1.592219] libphy: fec_enet_mii_bus: probed
[    1.606885] fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: registered PHC device 0
[    1.613883] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.620487] ehci-mxc: Freescale On-Chip EHCI Host driver
[    1.628031] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.647084] ci_hdrc ci_hdrc.0: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.652843] ci_hdrc ci_hdrc.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.683587] ci_hdrc ci_hdrc.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.698253] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.702545] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.717618] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.730961] input: iMX6UL Touchscreen Controller as /devices/soc0/soc/2000000.aips-bus/2040000.tsc/input/input0
[    1.750908] snvs_rtc 20cc000.snvs:snvs-rtc-lp: rtc core: registered 20cc000.snvs:snvs-r as rtc0
[    1.760393] i2c /dev entries driver
[    1.769849] IR NEC protocol handler initialized
[    1.774614] IR RC5(x/sz) protocol handler initialized
[    1.779735] IR RC6 protocol handler initialized
[    1.784383] IR JVC protocol handler initialized
[    1.788975] IR Sony protocol handler initialized
[    1.793698] IR SANYO protocol handler initialized
[    1.798460] IR Sharp protocol handler initialized
[    1.803216] IR MCE Keyboard/mouse protocol handler initialized
[    1.809147] IR XMP protocol handler initialized
[    1.818819] Driver for 1-wire Dallas network protocol.
[    1.835814] imx2-wdt 20bc000.wdog: timeout 60 sec (nowayout=0)
[    1.842347] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    1.846988] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    1.852186] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    1.860610] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.866985] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    1.871399] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    1.944150] mmc0: SDHCI controller on 2190000.usdhc [2190000.usdhc] using ADMA
[    1.972370] sdhci-esdhc-imx 2194000.usdhc: allocated mmc-pwrseq
[    2.049183] mmc0: new DDR MMC card at address 0001
[    2.054202] mmc1: SDHCI controller on 2194000.usdhc [2194000.usdhc] using ADMA
[    2.073896] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.079543] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.087169] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 004G60 3.69 GiB
[    2.091635] mmcblk0boot0: mmc0:0001 004G60 partition 1 2.00 MiB
[    2.110057] mmcblk0boot1: mmc0:0001 004G60 partition 2 2.00 MiB
[    2.124280] mmcblk0rpmb: mmc0:0001 004G60 partition 3 512 KiB
[    2.127167] random: fast init done
[    2.163821]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3
[    2.202947] ad7291: probe of 0-002b failed with error -5
[    2.219661] ad7291: probe of 0-0028 failed with error -5
[    2.232817] ad7291: probe of 0-002c failed with error -5
[    2.245991] ad7291: probe of 0-002e failed with error -5
[    2.260294] ad7291: probe of 0-002f failed with error -5
[    2.271157] ad7291: probe of 0-0020 failed with error -5
[    2.277839] ad7291: probe of 0-0022 failed with error -5
[    2.284355] ad7291: probe of 0-0023 failed with error -5
[    2.290613] 0-0035 supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    2.332144] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.370320] sit: IPv6, IPv4 and MPLS over IPv4 tunneling driver
[    2.391321] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.396669] bridge: automatic filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables has been deprecated. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[    2.409469] can: controller area network core (rev 20120528 abi 9)
[    2.416208] NET: Registered protocol family 29
[    2.420807] can: raw protocol (rev 20120528)
[    2.427567] can: broadcast manager protocol (rev 20160617 t)
[    2.433512] can: netlink gateway (rev 20130117) max_hops=1
[    2.440819] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    2.448746] cpu cpu0: dev_pm_opp_get_opp_count: OPP table not found (-19)
[    2.511731] input: gpio-keys as /devices/soc0/gpio-keys/input/input1
[    2.520111] snvs_rtc 20cc000.snvs:snvs-rtc-lp: setting system clock to 1970-01-01 00:09:20 UTC (560)
[    2.615271] vdd3p0: disabling
[    2.618343] 5V: disabling
[    2.622018] ALSA device list:
[    2.625126]   No soundcards found.
[    2.641654] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    2.650095] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    2.708695] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): recovery complete
[    2.717027] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.725495] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
[    2.736339] devtmpfs: mounted
[    2.742408] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1024K (c0c00000 - c0d00000)
[    2.857744] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: data=ordered
[    2.939440] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p3): recovery complete
[    2.945394] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p3): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Starting logging: OK
Starting mdev...
Initializing random number generator... done.
Starting system message bus: done
Starting network: [    4.657851] Micrel KSZ8081 or KSZ8091 2188000.ethernet:01: attached PHY driver [Micrel KSZ8081 or KSZ8091] (mii_bus:phy_addr=2188000.ethernet:01, irq=145)
[    4.676761] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
udhcpc: started, v1.26.2
udhcpc: sending discover
udhcpc: sending discover
udhcpc: sending discover
udhcpc: no lease, failing
FAIL
Starting dropbear sshd: OK
Starting lighttpd: OK
Starting sshd: key_load_private: invalid format
key_load_public: invalid format
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
key_load_private: invalid format
key_load_public: invalid format
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
key_load_private: invalid format
key_load_public: invalid format
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
key_load_private: invalid format
key_load_public: invalid format
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.
OK
/etc/init.d/rcS: line 26: /etc/init.d/S90init-carte-iminilide: Permission denied
hwclock: settimeofday: Invalid argument
hwclock :
Thu Jan  1 00:09:33 1970  0.000000 seconds
hwclock -r :
Thu Jan  1 00:09:33 1970  0.000000 seconds
date :
Thu Jan  1 01:09:32 CET 1970

Welcome to Armadeus development platform !
opos6ul login:
```

And here are the available u-boot commands :

```
BIOS> help
?       - alias for 'help'
askenv  - get environment variables from stdin
base    - print or set address offset
bdinfo  - print Board Info structure
bmode   - spi-nor|normal|usb|sata|ecspi1:0|ecspi1:1|ecspi1:2|ecspi1:3|esdhc1|esdhc2|esdhc3|esdhc4 [noreset]
bmp     - manipulate BMP image data
boot    - boot default, i.e., run 'bootcmd'
bootd   - boot default, i.e., run 'bootcmd'
bootefi - Boots an EFI payload from memory

bootm   - boot application image from memory
bootp   - boot image via network using BOOTP/TFTP protocol
bootz   - boot Linux zImage image from memory
clocks  - display clocks
cmp     - memory compare
coninfo - print console devices and information
cp      - memory copy
crc32   - checksum calculation
dhcp    - boot image via network using DHCP/TFTP protocol
dm      - Driver model low level access
dns     - lookup the IP of a hostname
echo    - echo args to console
editenv - edit environment variable
env     - environment handling commands
exit    - exit script
ext2load- load binary file from a Ext2 filesystem
ext2ls  - list files in a directory (default /)
ext4load- load binary file from a Ext4 filesystem
ext4ls  - list files in a directory (default /)
ext4size- determine a file's size
ext4write- create a file in the root directory
false   - do nothing, unsuccessfully
fatinfo - print information about filesystem
fatload - load binary file from a dos filesystem
fatls   - list files in a directory (default /)
fatsize - determine a file's size
fdt     - flattened device tree utility commands
fstype  - Look up a filesystem type
fuse    - Fuse sub-system
go      - start application at address 'addr'
gpio    - query and control gpio pins
grepenv - search environment variables
help    - print command description/usage
iminfo  - print header information for application image
imxtract- extract a part of a multi-image
itest   - return true/false on integer compare
load    - load binary file from a filesystem
loadb   - load binary file over serial line (kermit mode)
loads   - load S-Record file over serial line
loadx   - load binary file over serial line (xmodem mode)
loady   - load binary file over serial line (ymodem mode)
loop    - infinite loop on address range
ls      - list files in a directory (default /)
md      - memory display
mdio    - MDIO utility commands
meminfo - display memory information
mii     - MII utility commands
mm      - memory modify (auto-incrementing address)
mmc     - MMC sub system
mmcinfo - display MMC info
mtest   - simple RAM read/write test
mw      - memory write (fill)
nfs     - boot image via network using NFS protocol
nm      - memory modify (constant address)
ping    - send ICMP ECHO_REQUEST to network host
printenv- print environment variables
reset   - Perform RESET of the CPU
run     - run commands in an environment variable
save    - save file to a filesystem
saveenv - save environment variables to persistent storage
setenv  - set environment variables
setexpr - set environment variable as the result of eval expression
showvar - print local hushshell variables
size    - determine a file's size
sleep   - delay execution for some time
source  - run script from memory
test    - minimal test like /bin/sh
tftpboot- boot image via network using TFTP protocol
true    - do nothing, successfully
ums     - Use the UMS [USB Mass Storage]
usb     - USB sub-system
usbboot - boot from USB device
version - print monitor, compiler and linker version
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you have tried logging in as root with an [empty password](http://www.armadeus.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setup) ?

Comment: Yes, the SDK default password (root/empty password) was changed...

Comment: The `usbboot` option also seems promising. If you can find an image to boot, you could boot from USB and basically use the booted system to flash a fresh system, even backup the old one. If all you want is to gain access to the device, this is what I'd try. Next one would be a local BOOTP server against which I'd attempt a boot. Depending on your experience/skills either one of these could be faster for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the U-Boot console is a good entry point. Some ideas:

1. Add `single` to the kernel command line to boot in single user mode (no password).
2. The mmc command could allow flash dumping.
3. ext2/ext4 commands could allow you to read the /etc/shadow file with the password hashes.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to read /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow after adding "single" to command line parameters.

However, I've read that the "bootargs" environment variable stored the parameters, but modifying it (with setenv) didn't changed anything.

So after more careful reading of environment variabes, I've seen that I add to create a new variable called "extrabootargs" to add my parameters.

Thanks.